# Convert grib to netcdf file

Tags: netcdf4, grib, eccodes

I tried to convert grib to nc file using xarray wit this code:

```py
import xarray

data = xarray.open_dataset('E:/Thesis Dataset/Forecast/2017/dis_fore_012017.grib', engine='cfgrib') 
data.to_netcdf('E:/Thesis Dataset/Forecast/2017/dis_fore_012017.nc')
```

I have output like this:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 1
----> 1 data.to_netcdf('E:/Thesis Dataset/Forecast/2017/dis_fore_012017.nc')

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataset.py:1901, in Dataset.to_netcdf(self, path, mode, format, group, engine, encoding, unlimited_dims, compute, invalid_netcdf)
   1898     encoding = {}
   1899 from ..backends.api import to_netcdf
-> 1901 return to_netcdf(
   1902     self,
   1903     path,
   1904     mode,
   1905     format=format,
   1906     group=group,
   1907     engine=engine,
   1908     encoding=encoding,
   1909     unlimited_dims=unlimited_dims,
   1910     compute=compute,
   1911     invalid_netcdf=invalid_netcdf,
   1912 )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\api.py:1081, in to_netcdf(dataset, path_or_file, mode, format, group, engine, encoding, unlimited_dims, compute, multifile, invalid_netcdf)
   1078 if multifile:
   1079     return writer, store
-> 1081 writes = writer.sync(compute=compute)
   1083 if path_or_file is None:
   1084     store.sync()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\common.py:166, in ArrayWriter.sync(self, compute)
    160 import dask.array as da
    162 # TODO: consider wrapping targets with dask.delayed, if this makes
    163 # for any discernible difference in perforance, e.g.,
    164 # targets = [dask.delayed(t) for t in self.targets]
--> 166 delayed_store = da.store(
    167     self.sources,
    168     self.targets,
    169     lock=self.lock,
    170     compute=compute,
    171     flush=True,
    172     regions=self.regions,
    173 )
    174 self.sources = []
    175 self.targets = []

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.py:981, in store(sources, targets, lock, regions, compute, return_stored, **kwargs)
    978 result = Delayed(name, dsk)
    980 if compute:
--> 981     result.compute(**kwargs)
    982     return None
    983 else:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py:167, in DaskMethodsMixin.compute(self, **kwargs)
    143 def compute(self, **kwargs):
    144     """Compute this dask collection
    145 
    146     This turns a lazy Dask collection into its in-memory equivalent.
   (...)
    165     dask.base.compute
    166     """
--> 167     (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
    168     return result

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py:452, in compute(*args, **kwargs)
    449     keys.append(x.__dask_keys__())
    450     postcomputes.append(x.__dask_postcompute__())
--> 452 results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    453 return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\threaded.py:76, in get(dsk, result, cache, num_workers, pool, **kwargs)
     73             atexit.register(pool.close)
     74             pools[thread][num_workers] = pool
---> 76 results = get_async(
     77     pool.apply_async,
     78     len(pool._pool),
     79     dsk,
     80     result,
     81     cache=cache,
     82     get_id=_thread_get_id,
     83     pack_exception=pack_exception,
     84     **kwargs
     85 )
     87 # Cleanup pools associated to dead threads
     88 with pools_lock:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py:486, in get_async(apply_async, num_workers, dsk, result, cache, get_id, rerun_exceptions_locally, pack_exception, raise_exception, callbacks, dumps, loads, **kwargs)
    484         _execute_task(task, data)  # Re-execute locally
    485     else:
--> 486         raise_exception(exc, tb)
    487 res, worker_id = loads(res_info)
    488 state["cache"][key] = res

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py:316, in reraise(exc, tb)
    314 if exc.__traceback__ is not tb:
    315     raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
--> 316 raise exc

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py:222, in execute_task(key, task_info, dumps, loads, get_id, pack_exception)
    220 try:
    221     task, data = loads(task_info)
--> 222     result = _execute_task(task, data)
    223     id = get_id()
    224     result = dumps((result, id))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py:121, in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    117     func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
    118     # Note: Don't assign the subtask results to a variable. numpy detects
    119     # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120     # operations in-place.
--> 121     return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122 elif not ishashable(arg):
    123     return arg

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.py:102, in getter(a, b, asarray, lock)
    100     c = a[b]
    101     if asarray:
--> 102         c = np.asarray(c)
    103 finally:
    104     if lock:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py:358, in ImplicitToExplicitIndexingAdapter.__array__(self, dtype)
    357 def __array__(self, dtype=None):
--> 358     return np.asarray(self.array, dtype=dtype)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py:522, in CopyOnWriteArray.__array__(self, dtype)
    521 def __array__(self, dtype=None):
--> 522     return np.asarray(self.array, dtype=dtype)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py:423, in LazilyIndexedArray.__array__(self, dtype)
    421 def __array__(self, dtype=None):
    422     array = as_indexable(self.array)
--> 423     return np.asarray(array[self.key], dtype=None)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cfgrib\xarray_plugin.py:156, in CfGribArrayWrapper.__getitem__(self, key)
    152 def __getitem__(
    153     self,
    154     key: xr.core.indexing.ExplicitIndexer,
    155 ) -> np.ndarray:
--> 156     return xr.core.indexing.explicit_indexing_adapter(
    157         key, self.shape, xr.core.indexing.IndexingSupport.BASIC, self._getitem
    158     )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py:712, in explicit_indexing_adapter(key, shape, indexing_support, raw_indexing_method)
    690 """Support explicit indexing by delegating to a raw indexing method.
    691 
    692 Outer and/or vectorized indexers are supported by indexing a second time
   (...)
    709 Indexing result, in the form of a duck numpy-array.
    710 """
    711 raw_key, numpy_indices = decompose_indexer(key, shape, indexing_support)
--> 712 result = raw_indexing_method(raw_key.tuple)
    713 if numpy_indices.tuple:
    714     # index the loaded np.ndarray
    715     result = NumpyIndexingAdapter(np.asarray(result))[numpy_indices]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cfgrib\xarray_plugin.py:165, in CfGribArrayWrapper._getitem(self, key)
    160 def _getitem(
    161     self,
    162     key: T.Tuple[T.Any, ...],
    163 ) -> np.ndarray:
    164     with self.datastore.lock:
--> 165         return self.array[key]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cfgrib\dataset.py:347, in OnDiskArray.__getitem__(self, item)
    345 header_item = [{ix: i for i, ix in enumerate(it)} for it in header_item_list]
    346 array_field_shape = tuple(len(i) for i in header_item_list) + self.shape[-self.geo_ndim :]
--> 347 array_field = np.full(array_field_shape, fill_value=np.nan, dtype="float32")
    348 for header_indexes, message_ids in self.field_id_index.items():
    349     try:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py:343, in full(shape, fill_value, dtype, order, like)
    341     fill_value = asarray(fill_value)
    342     dtype = fill_value.dtype
--> 343 a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
    344 multiarray.copyto(a, fill_value, casting='unsafe')
    345 return a

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 38.8 GiB for an array with shape (51, 215, 950, 1000) and data type float32
```

My computer have 16 GB RAM, and when I check the performance there is still memory available. Also my python already for 64 bit. The data is EFAS river dicharge data from copernicus. Thanks for your help.

Comment: and my data is 12.5 gb

Answer (score 0):

Your data might be 12.5 GB on disk, where it is compressed, but a (51, 215, 950, 1000) array of float32s is 51 * 215 * 950 * 1000  * 4 bytes/float32 / 1024^3 = 39GB in memory.

Try processing the data in chunks, eg by passing `chunks={dimname: chunksize}` to `open_dataset`, eg:

```py
data = xarray.open_dataset('E:/Thesis Dataset/Forecast/2017/dis_fore_012017.grib', engine='cfgrib', chunks={"time": 10})
data.to_netcdf('E:/Thesis Dataset/Forecast/2017/dis_fore_012017.nc')
```

Or whatever your dimensions are.

Comment: I tried this 
import xarray

data = xarray.open_dataset('E:/Thesis Dataset/Forecast/2017/dis_fore_012017.grib', engine='cfgrib', chunks={"number": 51, 'step' : 215, 'y' : 95, 'x' : 100}) 
data

but still give this result
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 38.8 GiB for an array with shape (51, 215, 950, 1000) and data type float32

Comment: Did you load the data anywhere? Is this all of the code?

Comment: No, I load the data using xarray,open_dataset. Yes, this is all the code that I find to convert the grib to netcdf file

Comment: which line is erroring? can you update your question to show all your code and the full traceback (from `Traceback (most recent call last)` to the `MemoryError` line)? and try adding `data.sum().load()` before the write to see if the issue is in reading the data in chunks or in writing to netcdf. thanks!

Comment: I already update the question. The issue is when trying to convert

Comment: Can you try the sum().load() experiment though? And your traceback corresponds to writing a chucked array. Can you make sure your code matches exactly what you’re running to get that traceback? Thanks!

Comment: I tried the sum().load() and the output is exactly the memoryerror

Comment: great! ok so that tells us that the problem is in reading the grib file, not in writing to netCDF. I'm not as familiar with reading grib files, and it's possible xarray can't read them in chunks, but it seems you're getting the memory error because the file can't be chunked on read and the entire file size is (much) larger than your available memory. I would definitely try updating to the latest version of all packages in case this has been fixed, but if not, I'd probably try using a purpose-built tool like NCL to do your conversion.